# For loop seems to modify object in the next iteration which misses with the if else if structure

Tags: java, for-loop, netbeans

I'm creating a java desktop application that deals with students' absence in a school, so i'm adding and modifying absences that are made by a single or a group of students.

I've created a Student class and within it i have an Arraylist which holds the objects of absences made by that student.
An Absence object represents a day missed by a student, this absence can be either justified or unjustified(here is the modifying part i mentioned earlier)

Student class

```java
public class Student implements Serializable{
    private String cef,nom,prenom,filliere;
    private int nbHR_Justifie,nbHR_NonJustifie,nbRetards;//count of justified and unjustified days of absence and count of days that a student came late
    private ArrayList<Absence> listDesAbsence;
    private ArrayList<Retard> listDesRetard;

public boolean addAbsence(Absence abs){
        try{
            this.listDesAbsence.add(abs);
            if(abs.isJustified()){
                setNbHR_J(getNbHR_Justifie()+1);
            }else
                setNbHR_NonJustifie(getNbHR_NonJustifie()+1);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean addRetard(Retard ret){//add a "student came late" object
        try{
            this.listDesRetard.add(ret);
            this.setNbRetard(this.getNbRetard()+1);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Absence class is nothing special :constructor and getters and setters

This is the Main JFrame with a JTable (https://i.stack.imgur.com/stYTe.png) in which the user should select one or more students to add to them absences or modify the nature of absences from justified to unjustified or the opposite

```java
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private  DbConnection db;
    int[] numRows=jTable1.getSelectedRows();
        if(numRows.length==0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JPanel(), "you have to select at least one student");
        }else{
            String [] tabCEF=new String[numRows.length];
                for(int i=0;i<numRows.length;i++){
                    tabCEF[i]=(String) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(numRows[i], 0);
                }
            RetardRegulator ar=new RetardRegulator();
            ar.setTabCEF(tabCEF);
            ar.setVisible(true);
```

Now this is a class i'm calling AbsenceRegulator which extends a JFrame and should add or modify absence made by a single or a group of students that are selected in a jTable in the Main JFrame

```java
public class AbsenceRegulator extends javax.swing.JDialog {
DbConnection db;
    private String[] tabCEF;
    public AbsenceRegulator() {
        initComponents();
       db=new DbConnection();
    }
    public void setTabCEF(String[] tab){
        tabCEF=tab;
    }
private void jLabel4MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

        boolean justified;
        Absence abs;
        Student s;
        if(jRadioButton_NO.isSelected()){
            justified=false;
        }else{
            justified=true;
        }
        if(jDateChooser1.getCalendar()!=null){
            GregorianCalendar gc=(GregorianCalendar) jDateChooser1.getCalendar();
            abs=new Absence(gc,jTextArea1.getText(),justified);
            for(int i=0;i<tabCEF.length;i++){
                s=db.getStudent(tabCEF[i]);
                if(!s.dateAbsenceAlreadyTaken(gc) && !s.dateRetardAlreadyTaken(gc)){
                    s.addAbsence(abs);
                }
                else if(!s.dateAbsenceAlreadyTaken(gc) && s.dateRetardAlreadyTaken(gc)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date exite deja parmi les retards de cet etudiant");
                }
                else if(s.dateAbsenceAlreadyTaken(gc) && !s.dateRetardAlreadyTaken(gc)){
                    if(s.getAbsence(gc).isJustified() && !justified){
                        s.getAbsence(gc).setJustified(justified);
                        s.getAbsence(gc).setComment(jTextArea1.getText());
                        s.setNbHR_J(s.getNbHR_Justifie()-1);
                        s.setNbHR_NonJustifie(s.getNbHR_NonJustifie()+1);
                    }
                    else if(!s.getAbsence(gc).isJustified() && justified){
                        s.getAbsence(gc).setJustified(justified);
                        s.getAbsence(gc).setComment(jTextArea1.getText());
                        s.setNbHR_J(s.getNbHR_Justifie()+1);
                        s.setNbHR_NonJustifie(s.getNbHR_NonJustifie()-1);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                db.saveStudents();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"vous devez entrez une date");
        }
        }
```

I have no problem inserting new Absences to one or more students,(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4ZTY.png) but when I try to modify an absence by more than one students something weird happens,it seams that in the first iteration of the for loop in the AbsenceRegulator Class i essentially modify all this particular Absence in All students which makes the program skips the last ELSE IF  that's meant to modify the values accordingly.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzAjA.png)
i know that this seems impossible but I'm at my wits end here and can't see what's the problem

Comment: The usual reason for this is that you're reusing an object in a loop instead of creating a new one on each iteration. Moving variables to the smallest scope possible helps prevent this problem (for example, `abs` should live *inside* your loop).

Comment: @chrylis This worked like a charm,could you please explain why, I feel like I'm missing on a key concept of object oriented programming

Comment: A *variable* is just a placeholder that points to an *object*. You can make new objects and not put them in variables, or you can put a series of references to different objects into the same variable. In your original code, it looks like you only created one single `Absence` object and then modified it extensively instead of creating several different ones.